# Python Flask application to upload a file and save the path in MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

I want to upload an excel file and the file path needs to store in the database(MySQL) and file saves in my local directory.
I can upload file and able to save it in my local dir but MySQL I cannot see it anything!!

```
import os
from random import randint
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template, jsonify, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

# volume settings
VOLUME_PATH = './uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'xlsx', 'csv', 'xls'])
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:user@localhost/sample1'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


def allowed_file(filename):
  # this has changed from the original example because the original did not work for me
    return filename[-3:].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


class FileEntry(db.Model):
    """Simple file entry class."""
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    upload_id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)
    file = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    file_path = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)




@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    # check if the post request has the files part
    if 'files[]' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
    for file in files:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    flash('File(s) successfully uploaded')
    return redirect('/')

    # get uploaded file bytes


    fh = request.files['file']

    # generate upload id
    _id = randint(1, 100000)

    # generate file name
    file_name = '%s.xls' % _id

    # generate absolute file path
    file_path = os.path.join(VOLUME_PATH, file_name)

    # write file to storage
    fh.save(file_path)

    #   add entry into database
    file_entry = FileEntry(
        upload_id=_id,
        file=file_name,
        file_path=file_path
    )

    db.session.add(file_entry)
    db.session.commit()
    return ('FILE UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create database entries
    db.create_all()

    # run flask application
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Few things seem immediately wrong-- first you `return redirect('/')` which would stop all processing-- the code beneath that would never be executed.  Also you seem to expect a collection of files (`for file in files`) when saving it to the upload dir, but later you seem to expect only a single file, and don't iterate.